# How to install a program to open GMV files (Ubuntu/MacOS X)?

Tags: ubuntu

I am using a finite element framework called [deal ii](http://www.dealii.org/). In the [fourth tutorial](http://www.dealii.org/6.2.1/doxygen/tutorial/index.html) it is generating a GMV file. It should contain the information needed to draw the mesh that I'm using which looks like this.

[image]

Could someone give instructions on how to install a program (for Ubuntu or Mac OS X) which will open this file?

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to open it in [General Mesh Viewer](http://www.generalmeshviewer.com/).